# Which parameter we can use for window.WebChat.render WebChat so that provide custom URL parameters? using Azure Bot Frameworks Nodejs

Tags: javascript, botframework, web-chat

Pass Custom Parameters from webchat control to bot framework
which one is related to bot URL, we want to fetch/render?
i.e. more detailed example 
scenario:

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            token: token,
            ....
            ...
            customUrl : "mybot.net?q1=abc&&q2=xyz
        }),
        styleSet: styleSet,
        store: store
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

is that possible to pass different url parameters along with token, i.e. so that bot render the specific functionalities on the basis of parameters i.e. for q2=xyz sports related questions card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to send specific parameters when creating your Direct Line object. The Direct Line parameters are proprietary to that service - there would be no way to retrieve any custom values you sent.

However, the accepted method for sending data between the Web Chat client / user and the bot is to use the Web Chat `store` and the `dispatch()` function. The `store` broadcasts a variety of [actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions), such as `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED` and `DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY` (among others), that allows you to perform functions when triggered.

In your case (not knowing the full details), you may want to send the values as an event after Web Chat loads. The code would look something like this:

```js
<script>
  (async function () {
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        console.log('Event dispatched');
        dispatch( {
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'CUSTOM_PARAMETERS',
            value: { q1: 'abc', q2: 'xyz' }
          }
        } )
      }

      return next(action);
    });

    [...]

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
       directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      store: store
      />,
    document.getElementById( 'webchat' );
    )
  })
</script>
```

In your bot, you would utilize the `onEvent()` activity handler to capture the dispatched event:

```js
this.onEvent = async (context, next) => {
  console.log('Event activity detected');

  const { activity } = context;

  if (activity && activity.name === 'CUSTOM_PARAMETERS') {
    await context.sendActivity('Custom parameters received!');
  }

  await next();
};
```

If you have your bot backend on C# you will receive your custom parameters on the OnEventActivityAsync method

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     if(turnContext.Activity.Name == "CUSTOM_PARAMETERS")
       {
          await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($" Your custom parameters are: {turnContext.Activity.Value}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
       }
}
```

There are a variety of [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples#samples-list) you can reference that detail how to implement different functionalities, including how to send, receive, and act on specific points of data in Web Chat.

Hope of help!